# Blank page of Passport doodled/scribbled by kid

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports

My kid wrote A,B,C with pen on two blank pages of My India Passport, fortunately not any visa or identification page.

I have to travel back to India from USA, will it be ok or should I get renew passport considering this as damaged one?

Does anyone know if passport can be still used for immigration if blank pages are scribbled but visa and ID page is intact?

Comment: You can always claim that the officer at previous immigration wrote that there, and you have no idea why he did so. Many countries write all kind of stuff in my passport, and nobody ever cared.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see where are you going to use your passport and why

1. Airport, check in desk. They want to verify your identity and that you will be let in the country when you land. Your document suffices for both. They won't even notice the problem, most likely.
2. Exit checks. Yay, the USA doesn't have exit checks.
3. Indian border. You only need to prove your citizenship to be let in and even a damaged passport will suffice for that -- which is why the airport won't give you a hard time. There's nothing India specific here, really, allowing the entrance of citizens into their own country is a fundamental tenet of modern (=post World War II) citizenship.

Replace immediately when back home because entering another country with it might not be possible. Request to keep it so you can still use your visas in the old passport. (I've entered the USA for example countless times with a new passport and a ten year B1/B2 visa in my old, expired, invalidated passport.)

Comment: and do expect to get comments from the people at the checkin desk and/or passport control about your passport needing replacement.

Comment: I would much rather expect that from passport control if at all. Check in desk has no reason to page through an Indian passport going to India and they are busy. Border control also has no real reason either but they might just do it because, well, they are border control.

Comment: true. I've had it happen at a checkin desk for a small tear in the front of the passport. That's clearly visible even on a cursory look of course.